# excluding a class from global error class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have the jquery code to loop over fields from a list to add the class like this:

```
var a= data.fields.split(",");
$.each(a,function(i){
    $("#"+a[i]).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');   
 });
```

but now one of the div have a insider div like this:

```
<div class="input-group-addon">/</div>
```

and i am trying the the `has-error` class should not get applied it to it, but it is covering this up because of the has-error on **parent div**

Comment: more a css question. overwrite the parameters you don't want to be inherited from parent element.

Comment: and that is what i am trying to add a css using jquery

Comment: I think what Jeff means is that this can be accomplished purely with CSS and jQuery is not required. You would just need to set some styles on your child element that override the behavior you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Add a style for `.has-error .input-group-addon` that overrides the style inherited from `.has-error`, e.g.

```
.has-error {
    background-color: red;
}
.has-error .input-group-addon {
    background-color: white;
}
```

BTW, instead of the `.each` loop you can create a selector that matches all those IDs.

```
var ids = data.fields.split(",").map(id => "#" + id).join(",");
$(ids).closest('.form-group').not(":has(.input-group-addon)").addClass('has-error');
```

Comment: it is not adding the class to the whole div, i want it to have a class on parent div but the inside input-group-addon should inherit its value, something like overwriting the css will work i assume for that specific class

Comment: Sounds like you need a style for `.has-error .input-group-addon` that overrides the style that's inherited from `.has-error`.

Comment: right, i need to keep style for parent but overwrite for child